# Javascript function instead of refresh when pressing F5

Tags: javascript, html

I want to prevent the page from actually reloading and then run the function `reload()` when the user presses the F5 key.

Is that possible, and how?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Are you breaking the history of the page? Learn about the history api for html5.

Comment: There are many ways to refresh a page besides F5. Doing this will upset your users.  You can make use of the `window.onbeforeunload` callback to execute something when a page exited.

Comment: I'd like to chime in here and say this is a terrible idea. You should never try to take over the "standard" functions of the browser.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I don't want to take over the function, I wan to use JS to reload the page after running some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent refresh on `f5` using `preventDefault`  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnZQJ/1/)

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 116){ // f5 keycode is 116
       e.preventDefault();
       e.returnValue = false; // for IE
    }
}​
```

Comment: @DJDavid98 - you would be advised to check this carefully in all browsers that you want to support. I'm pretty sure it doesn't work in all browsers.

Comment: It supposed to work in all browsers. I am using this for different purpose.